# is it possible to use greek letters in R in strings

Tags: r

Is it possible to write with greek letters in R, as you can in Mathematica? In a string would be enough. It would be nice to use greek letters with rSymPy.

Not talking about plots, more interested in using greek letters in strings.

Comment: In variable/object names? I don't think so. In plots? [Yes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html).

Comment: @r2evans sure it is! Copy/paste the `β <- 1` into your console, and then look at the value of `β`. (May depend on your editor/locale settings, but I'm on American  locale Windows with RStudio and it worked just  fine. I *think* if your editor supports unicode you're good to go.)

Comment: My emacs/ess does *not* do that, unfortunately. \*shrug\* Not the most important thing I need to address today :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use unicodes to add greek letters to your string.

```
> str <- paste("\U03B1","\U03B2","\U03B6","\U03B4","\U03C0","\U03A8")
> str
[1] "α β ζ δ π Ψ"
```

Hope this answers your question.